# OverflowException when trying to sum the Bytes of two Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, overflow

I'm trying to sum the second index of an Array and the second index of another Array, assigning the sum to a `Int64` variable:

```
Dim value_array(60) As Byte
Dim myBytes1() As Byte = MyStringConversions.StringToByteArray(Substr_Cid) 
Dim sum As Int64

value_array(1) = &HFE
myBytes1(1) = &HFC
sum = value_array(1) + myBytes1(1)
```

I'm getting a `OverflowException`.
I don't know why, `Int64` can easily fit  `01FA` in hex.

Comment: You most probably get a NullReferenceException: `Dim myBytes1() As Byte` => the array it's not initialized when you try to set a value. Also, remember that collections are initialized at Index 0 and VB.Net sets the Upper bound: `value_array(60)` will contain 61 elements.

Comment: @Jimi it is contains values and initialized

Comment: Dim myBytes1() As Byte = MyStringConversions.StringToByteArray(Substr_Cid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arithmetic operation you're performing sums a `Byte` value to a `Byte` value.
The result of the sum is then assigned to a `Long` variable type.
The assignment occurs after the operation has been performed.

Since you're summing `myBytes1(1)` to `value_array(1)`:

```
Dim sum As Int64 = value_array(1) + myBytes1(1)
```

and `value_array` is of type `Byte`, the sum value goes beyond what `Byte.MaxValue = 255` can contain.
Hence the [`OverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception).

To avoid the exception, cast or convert the value you're summing to the destination type.
Since this is a [widening conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions), no overflow can occur:

Sum a `Long` to a `Long`:

```
Dim sum As Long = CType(value_array(1), Long) + CType(myBytes1(1), Long)
```

or sum a `Byte` to a `Long`:

```
Dim sum As Long = CLng(value_array(1)) + myBytes1(1)
```

But not:

```
Dim sum As Int64 = CLng(value_array(1) + myBytes1(1))
```

Here, the conversion is performed *after* the arithmetic operation has already overflowed `Byte.MaxValue`.

Comment: thank you a lot, can you please also help me with how to assign integer to the byte without overflow, I want the last byte of integer to be assigned to the byte

Comment: Sure, `[Byte Value] = CByte([Integer Value] And &HFF)`. This will `AND` to `1` the lower Byte and `AND` to `0` the others.